# How to most professionally phrase "distribution company"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to correctly describe the company I worked for.

It's a printing company who works for other companies, like pizzerias and other franchises, and prints fliers and banners and logos for those companies. What professional phrase can I use to describe a company like that?

Comment: I'd go with _print shop_.

Comment: Do they just print these items or do they also distribute them (like by hanging them on doors and windshields)?

Comment: Where did the term "distribution company" come from?  To me, a distribution company and a printing company don't have a whole lot in common.

Comment: The term "jobbing printer" is perfectly appropriate, but perhaps when you say "professional phrase" you are actually looking for something that enhances the status?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments on the OP, a "better" term could rely on more context.

If your company simply prints the materials and the customer distributes them, then it is often called a *print shop*.

If your company prints the materials and sends them out to the recipients via post, it could be a *mail marketer* or *mailing service*.

If your company prints the materials and sends couriers out to the recipients to deliver by hand, it could be a *marketing distributor*.